# Using Mapbox tiles with folium

Tags: python, mapbox, folium

I cannot find correct usage for using custom mapbox tilesets with folium.

From the documentation, "Folium also supports Cloudmade and Mapbox custom tilesets- simply pass your key to the API_key keyword" (http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html).

The docs provide this example...

```
folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750],
           tiles='Mapbox',
           API_key='your.API.key')
```

So I have tried...

```
#Create Map
my_map = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972],
                    zoom_start=12,
                    tiles='Mapbox',
                    API_key = 'pk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') #mapbox map id 


#Create Map
my_map = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972],
                    zoom_start=12,
                    tiles='Mapbox',
                    API_key = 'pk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')#mb api key 

#Create Map
 my_map = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972],
                    zoom_start=12,
                    tiles='user.2fb7fc73',
                    API_key = 'pk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    attr='Mapbox Data Attribution')
```

I have not been able to find any more example usage or explanation in the documents. If anyone has had success please advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html "Folium supports passing any Leaflet.js compatible custom tileset" let lets try that and bypass it's built in support:

```
folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972],
       zoom_start=12,
       tiles='"http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/wtgeographer.2fb7fc73/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.xxx',
       attr='XXX Mapbox Attribution')
```

You'll need to places the pk.xxx with your pubilc access token.

This uses the [API for Mapbox Studio Classic styles](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-tiles).

Comment: To use your own custom styles directly (rather than the default mapbox styles/tiles), see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352459/144420

Answer (score 4):

[The answer above is correct](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203117/107424), but I wanted to add some detail of where Mapbox users can get the necessary url for the code. When in Mapbox Styles page, simply choose to share your style, and under 'Developer Resources', change the method to Fulcrum as pictured below. Then, simply copy the link from the integration url and paste in the tiles=' '.

[image: Fulcrum Method]

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to get this link, with classic mapbox API above, you just needed to upload the tileset and could link. Now you need to manually add to studio? What if you have hundreds of tiles. Or multiple time slices of the same geography that your app needs to choose? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366018/programmatic-way-of-accessing-mapbox-tileset-from-leaflet-without-studio

Comment: @bw4sz, sounds like you may be better off hosting your tiles with maptiler which allows a certain number (I dont know how much) to be hosted in their cloud for free. https://cloud.maptiler.com/