# Map IDs to add Mapbox basemaps to Leaflet or OpenLayers

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, mapbox, basemap

I would like to add Mapbox basemaps to Leaflet or OpenLayers, but I am missing the map IDs.

Before **Mapbox Editor** was deactivated, one could easily create and save a map, copy that map's ID and your personal API token and then include the map in Leaflet or OpenLayers by using the following URL, replacing *my.map* and your *< access token here >*:

```
http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/my.map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=<your access token here>
```

This still works. But **only** if you have existing maps from **before** Mapbox Editor was deactivated on January 31, 2017.

How do new users, who cannot save maps and therefore do not have a personal map ID, go about formatting the URL? New users get an API token but they cannot save maps anymore and thereby get a map ID.

So, how can the following Mapbox basemaps be accessed now:

- Classic
- Light
- Dark
- Satellite
- Satellite Streets
- Wheatpaste
- Streets Classic
- Comic
- Outdoors
- Run, Bike, Hike
- Pencil
- Pirates
- Emerald
- High Contrast

I found a post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37167777/2948869), which shows that the URL can be formatted this way:

```
 https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}
```

So, you do not necessarily need a personal map ID as every public Mapbox basemap seems to have an ID.

I have tested this and it works, you just need to replace *{id}* with a map's name, such as *streets-v9* but I am unable to find the IDs of the above maps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me quote from https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps :

> If you use Mapbox.js, Mapbox GL JS, or another library like Leaflet,
> you're already using this API. This documentation is geared toward
> software developers who want to programmatically read these resources:
> it isn't necessary to read or understand this reference to design or
> use maps.
>
> #### Mapbox classic map IDs
>
> The following map IDs are accessible to all accounts using a valid
> access token:
>
> ```
> mapbox.streets
> mapbox.light
> mapbox.dark
> mapbox.satellite
> mapbox.streets-satellite
> mapbox.wheatpaste
> mapbox.streets-basic
> mapbox.comic
> mapbox.outdoors
> mapbox.run-bike-hike
> mapbox.pencil
> mapbox.pirates
> mapbox.emerald
> mapbox.high-contrast
> ```

So you should use something like

`http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=...`

Comment: I found that but it did not work. I will try again soon and let you know.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Had a minor error in the URL and that kept it from working!

Comment: You should edit my answer to fix that typo in the URL :-)

Comment: These identifiers like mapbox.comic, are no longer listed in the Mapbox documentation, at least not in the URL provided here. Therefore this answer is helpful to provide these IDs, which *still work*

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I would like to contribute here, because I managed to make it work: I am using jupyter notebook, and python 3.7.

First of all, the updated names of the mapbox styles are here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#styles

Then FINALLY this code under worked perfectly well:

```
map_mapbox_custom = folium.Map(
    location=[60, 2], 
    zoom_start=5, 
    tiles='https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=mytoken',
    attr='mapbox')

map_mapbox_custom
```

Note:

- I had to write in full my mapbox token (starting with 'pk.') in place of 'mytoken', otherwise I had a blank map!
- You've got to leave {z}/{x}/{y} like that, don't try to replace them with values! it is what you specify under 'location' and 'zoom_start' which will dictate the extension and zoom of your map.

I hope this will help, but let me know in the comments if stuff is still not working for you :-)

See screenshot under...
[image: Folium map with mapbox in jupyter notebook]

Comment: this is the more useful answer because it shows how you can use custom styles you create directly via the API! Just replace the /mapbox/light-v10/ part of the url with /{username}/{style_id}, something like /spcogg/2ijf23QTFf/ (not a real id)